# Trying to install AudioCraft to Linux Mint 21.2 but getting error: subprocess-exited-with-error

Tags: python, linux

I followed the installation guide of GitHub and installed PyTorch 2.0 and Python 3.9, and ffmpeg. All went fine untill I tried to install the actual AudioCraft by command

`pip install -U audiocraft`

It starts the install, but gives then this error:

```
Preparing metadata (setup.py) ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error
  
  × python setup.py egg_info did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [8 lines of output]
      Traceback (most recent call last):
        File "<string>", line 2, in <module>
        File "<pip-setuptools-caller>", line 34, in <module>
        File "/tmp/pip-install-sqg7114f/xformers_15b652520912479eb54a35e13383f8c5/setup.py", line 239, in <module>
          ext_modules=get_extensions(),
        File "/tmp/pip-install-sqg7114f/xformers_15b652520912479eb54a35e13383f8c5/setup.py", line 157, in get_extensions
          raise RuntimeError(
      RuntimeError: CUTLASS submodule not found. Did you forget to run `git submodule update --init --recursive` ?
      [end of output]
  
  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: metadata-generation-failed

× Encountered error while generating package metadata.
╰─> See above for output.

note: This is an issue with the package mentioned above, not pip.
hint: See above for details.
```

I tried to search solutions and found some similar cases. I tried to apply their solutions but didn't succeed and ran out of energy and knowledge. (I am just non-coder Linux Mint hobby user.)

What could be done?

Answer (score 1):

You can use conda to install xformers, and it really works.

```
conda install xformers -c xformers
```